# Having two forms open and running a method on form1 from form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program which I am using to manage a database.  My database table contents are displayed in a `listview` on form1.  I am using `form2` to edit the database.
When `form2` is open `form1` is still visible.

However, when form2 is closed, after updating the database, I would like form1 to refresh its `listview` to show the newly updated information.

I have a method which refreshes the `listview` on `form1`. How can I execute this from `form2`?

I have set the method to public but I still cannot access it from `form2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, one way would be to register an event when you create `Form2`:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Closed += (sender, args) => this.RefreshListView();
```

The [`Form.Closed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event will be fired when form2 closes. One of the advantages of doing this with events is that `Form2` doesn't need to know anything about `Form1` reducing code coupling.

Comment: Thanks for that, worked a charm.
Here is my code:
private void btnAddHomeworker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddHomeworker ah = new AddHomeworker();
            ah.FormClosing += (sender1, args) => this.AllHomeworkers();
            ah.Show();
        }

Answer (score 1):

Pass an instance of form1 to form2's constructor:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
```

In form2's constructor, store the reference to the form1 object as a member variable.

Then, from the relevant part of form2, just call the method on form1:

```
form1.RefreshListView();
```